# Gorenstein projective module over commutative local algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a local commutative finite dimensional algebra over a field $K$.

An $A$-module $M$ is called Gorenstein projective if $M$ is reflexive, $Ext_A^i(M,A)=0=Ext_A^i(M^{*},A)$ for all $i>0$ with $M^{*}=Hom_A(M,A)$. If $A$ is Gorenstein this coincides with the maximal Cohen-Macaulay modules.

> Question 1: Is there a classification when $A$ has the property that every Gorenstein projective $A$-module is free?

One example for this is $K[x,y]/(x^2,y^2,xy)$.

> Question 2: Is there a classification when $A$ has only finitely many indecomposable Gorenstein proejctive $A$-modules and at least one that is not free?

Examples are $K[x]/(x^n)$, but actually I do not know any other example at the moment. Is there any?

Comment: It may be helpful to know that 1 is referred to as CM-free, while 2 is CM-finite but not CM-free. It is known that radical square zero Artin algebras are either symmetric or CM-free (X.-W. Chen), explaining your first example. Symmetric Artin algebras of finite representation type are CM-finite, but then if you're only interested in commutative ones, that just gives your second example.

Comment: In the commutative algebra community, we call Noetherian local rings as in your Question(1) to be G-regular. These rings have some nice ascent/descent properties as can be found in Section 4 of the beautiful paper https://doi.org/10.1080/00927870802179602 , Section 5 of which also gives some large class of examples of such rings ...

Comment: Regarding Question 2, if a local ring has finitely many indecomposable Gorenstein projective modules, and at least one non-free, then the ring must have isolated singularity and must be an abstract hypersurface (i.e. the completion is regular local modulo a single element); this is Theorem 4.5 of the breakthrough paper https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aim.2008.03.005 ... finally assuming the ring is complete, since you now know it is a hypersurface of finite CM type, so you have a full classification of such rings by (ADE)-singularity (due to works of Buchweitz, Greuel, Schreyer, Knörrer, Solberg)

Comment: you may also be interested to know that your example to Question 1 has maximal ideal square = zero, hence it has minimal multiplicity, so Golod, so G-regular (see Lemma 5.1 of https://doi.org/10.1080/00927870802179602 )

Comment: @sdey Thanks, if you want you can turn those comments into an answer.

Comment: @Mare: done now. Sorry it took a while :(

Answer (score 3):

Regarding Question 2, if a local ring has finitely many indecomposable Gorenstein projective modules, and at least one non-free, then the ring must have isolated singularity and must be an abstract hypersurface (i.e. the completion is regular local modulo a single element); this is Theorem 4.5 of the breakthrough paper https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aim.2008.03.005 ... finally assuming the ring is complete, since you now know it is a hypersurface of finite CM type, so you have a full classification of such rings by (ADE)-singularity (due to works of Buchweitz, Greuel, Schreyer, Knörrer, Solberg).

you may also be interested to know that your example to Question 1 has maximal ideal square = zero, hence it has minimal multiplicity, so Golod, so G-regular (see Lemma 5.1 of https://doi.org/10.1080/00927870802179602 )